# Day light savings offset for a given timezone/region

Tags: javascript, timezone, dst

How do we get Day light Savings (DST) difference for a given timezone. I have my system in IST. Javascript Applications running on the system would try to know the DST for given timezone like 'Australia/Melbourne' . Looks like Java has zone.getDSTSavings () for same and trying to see similar for JavaScript.

Following javascript code returns diff as 0 as my OS timezone is 'Asia/Calcutta' which doesnt have day light Savings. How can I change this program to find out day light savings for different zone like 'Australia/Melbourne'  on my machine which should return 60 minutes as output.

```
let date = new Date(1995, 11, 17);
console.log(" current date ", date);



function getDSTChange(date, timezone) {
    if (timezone) {
         // ???
    }                                               
    const jan = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 1).getTimezoneOffset();
    const july = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 6, 1).getTimezoneOffset();
    let diff = Math.max(jan, july) - date.getTimezoneOffset();
    console.log(" Day light saving time ", diff);
    return diff;
}

getDSTChange(date, 'Asia/Calcutta'); // should return 0
getDSTChange(date, 'Australia/Melbourne'); // should return 60
```

Comment: You can derive the result from `Intl.DateTimeFormat("de", {timeZone: "...",timeStyle:"short"}).formatRange(new Date("xxxx-01-01"),new Date("xxxx-07-01"))`.

Comment: I think I should not do the above offset calculation , instead use Intl.DateTimeFormat  to directy get the date Object in that timezone. But I dont see a way to get date object with Intl.DateTimeFormat format method, It seems to have only return value as string

Comment: @PavanKumar - That's the best JS has built-in for now.  Improvements are coming with https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Comments/inputs. They are very helpful. A high level solution like using formatter.formatToParts array values to construct the date object of a different timezone works for now.

```
const formatter = Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { timeZone: 'Australia/Melbourne',
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric",
  timeZoneName: "short",
  fractionalSecondDigits: 3});
 
 
var formatted = formatter.formatToParts(date);
```